# Как выполнять javascript команды через TChromium?

Tags: java, delphi, tchromium

Пытаюсь выполнить JavaScript код в `TChromium`, но получаю ошибку:

> Память не может быть прочитана.

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var js: string;
begin
  js := 'document.execCommand(''SaveAs'')';
  chromium1.Browser.MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScript(js, 'http://www.google.ru/', 0);
end;
```

Comment: все же java или javascript?

Comment: ExecuteJavaScript - java script.

Comment: *Пытаюсь выполнить Java код*